# How to compose output of NDSolve with another function?

Tags: differential-equations, list-manipulation

If I want to solve some ODE by NDSolve but want to make a table of the solution $u(x)$ NDSolve gave me evaluated at another function, say $x(i)$, how would I do that,
here's an example

```
s = NDSolve[{u[0] == 0, u[10] == 0, u''[x] + u[x] == E^-x^2}, 
  u[x], {x, 0, 100}]
x[i_] := i^2
Table[Abs[Evaluate[u[x[i]] /. s] - (x[i])^2], {i, 1, 4}]
```

so I am solving the ODE and the defining a new funtion $x(i):=i^2$ and then I want the values $u(x(i))$, I tried writing u[x[i]]/.s but that doesn't work, how should one write this?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
U = NDSolveValue[{u[0] == 0, u[10] == 0, u''[x] + u[x] == E^-x^2},u , {x, 0, 100}]
x[i_] := i^2
Table[Abs[ U[x[i]]  - (x[i])^2], {i, 1, 4}]
(*{0.637001, 16.218, 80.3435, 255.782}*)
```

Hope it helps!